# how to remove i/o exception from given code

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;


     public class MyGraphic5 extends java.applet.Applet implements ActionListener
     {

         boolean go =false;
            int x, oldx, y, oldy;
            double angle;

    Button drawButton =new Button("Draw");


         public void init()
        {
                add(drawButton);
                drawButton.addActionListener(this);
       }
     public void paint(Graphics screen)
       {
             resize(500,500);
             int x,y, oldx, oldy;
             double i=0;
             double a=0;
             double b=0;
             oldx=250;
             oldy=250;
             double ang=0;
             //oldx=(int)(a*Math.cos(i)+250);
             //oldy=(int)(b*Math.sin(i)+250);
             double angle;
             x=1;
           if (go==true)
           {
             for (i=0; i<800; i=i+1)
             {
                //screen.drawOval(175-i,80,i*2+10,10+i); //(x1,y1,width,height)
                a=a+.5;
                b=b+.5;
                ang=ang+.8;
                x=(int)(a*Math.cos(ang)+250);
                y=(int)(b*Math.sin(ang)+250);
                screen.drawLine(x,y, oldx, oldy);
                oldx=x;
                oldy=y;
                pause(1);
             }

           }
       }
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
       {

                Object source = event.getSource();
                if (source.equals(drawButton))
                {
                    System.out.println("hi");
                    go=true;
                    repaint();
                }

          }

       void pause(int time)
        {
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(time);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
           }

     }
```

Comment: It would help if you told us *where* the exception is happening.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: you might want to express more clearly your question (where is the problem? what kind of problem? what's the expected output? ...etc); also check how the code shows up (did you forget to include the `import` into the code?); also, if this is homework you should tag it appropriately.

Comment: I had the same problem I apparenlty can't ask questions properly. I wonder if there is a place to fix that XD. (School? lol)

Answer (score 2):

That code does not even contain anything that could throw an `IOException`.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code as is and was able to compile and run it in an appletviewer without an I/O Exception...so I don't know where the problem is...